# Outlook 2013 VBA: Refer to editor in reading pane

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am trying to assign a category to a message when sending it (a 'Send Now' category to override a send delay). The macro below works fine when editing the message in a separate window, but it hangs at the line 'Set msg = insp.CurrentItem' with error message 'Object variable or With block variable not set' when I try to run the macro while editing the message in the reading pane editor.

How do I properly refer to the editor when it is docked? And is there a condition test I can use to test what kind of editor is being used?

Thanks!

```
Public Sub SendNow()
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim insp As Outlook.Inspector

Set insp = Application.ActiveInspector
Set msg = insp.CurrentItem
    If insp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then ' outlook 2013
        msg.Categories = "Send Now"
    End If
msg.Save
msg.Send

Set insp = Nothing
Set msg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look:

```
 Set exp = Application.ActiveExplorer
 Set msg = exp.ActiveInlineResponse
 If Not msg Is Nothing Then
 ...
```